# Solving this equation to be 3 literals

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to solve this to be 3 literals, but I keep getting errors:

Question:$(x'y' + z)' + z + xy + wz$

My answer:

$(x+y)z' + xy + z(1+w)\implies xz' + yz' + xy + z\implies zx + zz' + yz' + xy$

$\implies zx + yz' + xy \implies xyz + xzz' + xy \implies xyz + xy \implies yx (1 + z)\implies yx$

The right answer should be $x + y + z$

Comment: I don't understand what you did to get from the second line to the third line ..

Comment: I distributed the z to the xz'

Comment: So that should be $(z+x)(z+z')$, instead of $zx+zz'$.

Comment: Use the @Poypoyan method to simplify the rest of the equation to achieve the expected answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is often quite useful to consider the negation of the given expression and then use

- $aa = a$
- $aa'=0$
- $a+ab = a(1+b) = a$

So, consider $E' = \left( (x'y' + z)' + z + xy + wz \right)'$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} E' 
& = & \left( (x'y' + z)' + z + xy + wz \right)' \\
& = & (x'y' + z)z'(xy)'(wz)' \\
& \stackrel{zz' = 0}{=}& x'y'z'(x'+y')(w'+z')  \\
& \stackrel{x'x' = x' etc.}{=}& x'y'z' + x'y'z'w' \\
& = & x'y'z'(1+ w' ) \\
& = & x'y'z' \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
$$\Rightarrow E = (x'y'z')' = x+y+z$$